# The config.php doesn't seem to work

Tags: php

In the home.html file, I have a div that when it is clicked it will show the login form to be filled by the user who want to login. After filling the form, the config of the form should direct it back to the home.html file.

The problem I encountered is, When I tried to fill the form of username and password field and submit that, the browser just stop blank in the config-haslogin.php, not direct it back to the home.html file.

The result is just the same when I tried to fill it with the wrong username and password.

**config-haslogin.php**

```
<?php @session_start();
$_SESSION['id']= 0;
?>


<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);      
mysql_connect("mysql.com","usename","password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("mytable")  or die("Fail");

$myemail= $_POST['email'];
$mypassword= $_POST['password'];

$sql= "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='".$myemail."' and password='".$mypassword."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1 ) 
{
echo "Login successful";
echo '<script>window.location="index.html";</script>';
}
 ?>
```

Comment: If you get a blank page, always enable error reporting first. Alternatively, look in the error logs of your web server.

Comment: Error suppression and deprecated extensions, oh my!

Comment: Oh right. The `mysql_*` functions are becoming deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. Don't write new code using them, use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Comment: **This is wrong on so many levels...** Stop suppressing errors from `session_start()` (you **really** want to know if there's a problem here), stop using `mysql_*` (it's deprecated), stop passing variables directly into SQL (used parameterised queries), start checking for errors with `mysql_*` (with `mysql_error()`), stop using Javascript to redirect your page (user can disable javascript - use `header("Location: index.html");`), etc...

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Not *"becoming"* deprecated

Comment: I have used header location. This is the alternative I try to use but the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
echo "Login successful";
'<script>window.location="index.html";</script>';
```

You are missing the echo statement there:

```
echo "Login successful";
echo '<script>window.location="index.html";</script>';
```

More, but not as grave, problematic parts of your code:

```
@session_start();
```

Suppressing error messages doesn't solve problems, it just creates new ones. You will not notice when an error occurs and will spend hours finding a solution for it when it would take you only minutes if you had a proper error message.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

This is only half the rent. It only defines which error levels to show, not if they are shown at all. If error messages are disabled by your hoster you have to do `ini_set("display_errors", true);` as well, otherwise you'll see nothing.

Your SQL code is vulnerable to SQL injections. I could just enter "mail@host.com' --" in your email field and be logged in without knowing the password. You should switch to `mysqli_*` or PDO and use prepared statemens for your queries.

Use proper error reporting. Don't just use this:

```
or die("cannot connect");
```

Instead relay the actual error message so you know WHY it didn't work:

```
or die("Connection error: " . mysql_error());
```

Use this after queries as well so you know why a query fails:

```
if ($result == false) echo "Query failed: " . mysql_error();
```

PDO and MySQLi have similar error reporting functions. Use them.

```
echo '<script>window.location="index.html";</script>';
```

You should not use JavaScript for redirections. You never know if the client has JavaScript enabled or is even capable of it. The proper way to do redirects is the `header()` function:

```
header("Location: index.html");
exit();
```

Note that `header()` will only work if there is absolutely NO output before it. Not even blanks, newlines or other whitespace.

Comment: Nice pickup. Replacing the semi-colon with a comma would have also worked.

Comment: It would, but it would be more difficult to understand to a beginner.

Comment: Fundamentally bad code should be explained to a beginner, there's plenty of other reasons why this code shouldn't be written the way it is.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am very very beginner. But, please help me to solve this, please.

Comment: @AlKush "doesn't work" is not a helpful error description. Look for error messages and post them in your question.

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /hermes/bosoraweb056/b650/ipg.thejakartadigitalcom/ecommerce/config-haslogin.php on line 20

Comment: @AlKush I just added some notes to my answer that will help you solve that.

Comment: this is the line of 20: $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: Login successful Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosoraweb056/b650/ipg.thejakartadigitalcom/ecommerce/config-haslogin.php:4) in /hermes/bosoraweb056/b650/ipg.thejakartadigitalcom/ecommerce/config-haslogin.php on line 24

Comment: @AlKush That would be the big chunk of whitespace between your two `<?php ... ?>` sections

Comment: I have deleted all the spaces between them but the result is just the same. :/

Comment: It works now. I just added: <?php
  ob_start();

  // code 

 ob_end_flush();
?>